# How can I get extra subtitles for chapter titles that also appear in the ToC?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, chapters

I have several chapter titles that I would like to combine with subtitles, typeset in italics.

For example,

> ### Chapter Title
>
> *A very fine chapter indeed …*

Now, I found an approach on how to do this [here](https://groups.google.com/group/latexusersgroup/browse_thread/thread/d3ba993fadc66379/a178fbbda4bf1157?q=%2522Bongani%2bNgwenya%2522#a178fbbda4bf1157&ei=iGwTS6eaOpW8Qpmqic0O&sa=t&ct=res&cd=1&source=groups&usg=AFQjCNFoIHLrogCcr8h25m6zMxuDFlArBA), introducing a new `\Chapter` command, which now looks like this:

```
\newcommand\Chapter[2]{
  \chapter[#1: {\itshape#2}]{#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}
}
```

This somewhat works (although it breaks TextMate's auto-recognition of chapters), but I would like these subtitles to also be visible in the Table of Contents.

Like so:

> ### Chapter Title                                                                                1
>
> *A very fine chapter indeed …*

Is there any way to achieve that? Note that my LaTeX fu is pretty limited, so I'm not sure where to even start.

Comment: This post might be useful for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69550/how-can-i-add-a-subtitle-to-a-section-title

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This simple solution should work for you. It is not formatted as you wished, but I really cannot imagine a ToC with subtitles *below* some title there.

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand\Chapter[2]{
  \chapter[#1: {\itshape#2}]{#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\Chapter{My chapter}{Nice subtitle}

Lorem ipsum ...

\chapter{Another chapter}

Lorem ipsum ...

\end{document}
```

**Alternative definition** of `\Chapter` to have the subtitle below the title in ToC:

```
\newcommand\Chapter[2]{\chapter
  [#1\hfil\hbox{}\protect\linebreak{\itshape#2}]%
  {#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}%
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without introducing a new command? I mean, would something like this work too: `\renewcommand\chapter[2]{\chapter[#1: {\itshape#2}]#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}}`?

Comment: @user5950 You have to store the old `\chapter` first. Therefore you need: `\let\oldchapter\chapter \renewcommand\chapter[2]{\oldchapter[#1: {\itshape#2}]#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}}`

Comment: However, `\chapter` has an optional argument by default which you remove by this. I'd stick to changing the command name.

Comment: The alternative definition works for me, but how would I go about removing the default `Chapter X` heading in chapters? I tried using `\chapter*` instead inside the new command, but it only ruins the layout.

Answer (score 2):

Tiny tweak of yo's answer :):

```
\usepackage{relsize} %Package to set relative font size (\smaller, \larger)

\documentclass{report}

\newcommand\Chapter[2]{
  \chapter[#1: {\itshape#2}]{#1\\\medskip\smaller\itshape#2}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\Chapter{My chapter}{Nice subtitle}

Lorem ipsum ...

\chapter{Another chapter}

Lorem ipsum ...

\end{document}
```

In that way you make your code adaptable to any font settings in your document:

- The space you add to the newline is `\medskip`, which is adapted to the document, not a fixed nummerical value `2ex`. You can use `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, or `\bigskip`, and see which fits you better.
- The size of the subtitle is relative to the title, `\smaller`. That is very important, first because we do not need to know the size of the chapter title, and second, if the title had size `\Large`, then, obviously, making the subtitle `\Large` makes no difference ;).
  The package `relsize` provides this command, which has an integer parameter to make it even smaller: you can use `\smaller{2}` or `\small{3}` and so on. `\smaller{1}` produces the same as `\smaller` alone.