# How can I add a subtitle to a section title?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, text-manipulation

I'd like to do this for some of my sections but not all. I'd also like to maintain the current spacing; for example, if the vspacing is 1cm from section title to body text (at 100% zoom), then I'd like it to be 1cm from the subtitle to body text.

Thanks.

Comment: Should this subtitle be part of the title (as in, appear in contents)? If so, why not simply use something like `\section{Section Title\\Section Subtitle}`?

Comment: That's a nice option. I tried it and it looks OK, but I'd like to have the subtitle in a smaller font that the title. Thing is, when I use `\section{Section Title\\ \large{Section Subtitle}}`, it makes the `Section Subtitle` into `large` _in the TOC_.

Comment: Then perhaps you can play with the short title argument of the `\section` command: would `\section[Section Title\\ Section Subtitle]{Section Title\\ \large{Section Subtitle}}` be what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes, that works excellently! And, it also gives me the option to remove the "Section Subtitle" argument from the `[...]`. Thanks all.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If the section's subtitle has to show up in the TOC, then use:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[Section Title. Section Subtitle]{Section 
   Title\\ {\large Section Subtitle}}
\section{Another Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @User17670 - In my solution, I suggest not using a line break but simply a period (full stop) to separate the main title and subtitle.

Comment: Yes, I noticed. Thanks for the input(!), although I already had a solution (which _IMO_ looks better) from Corentin Herbert. 

Also, I changed `\document class` to `\documentclass` in your post :p