# How can I create a 'little subtitle' for a section?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\section*{29th March 2014}
\textit{A little subtitle}

Here starts my first paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Here's a screencap of the resulting document:
[image: Resulting document]

I'd like the 'little subtitle', being part of the section title, to be situated above the horizontal line.

I assume the easiest way to implement this is to create a section format with two inputs: a "Date" and a "Little subtitle". In this case, my code would then be:

```
\section*{29th March 2014}{A little subtitle}
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Would the text be a fixed text?

Comment: Please see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69550/how-can-i-add-a-subtitle-to-a-section-title). Do not forget to see the comments to the question.

Comment: @Bernard: No, that's why I suggested to use a second input for the section title.

Comment: And what about the headers or the table of contents?

Comment: @Bernard: I'm not displaying a table of contents, but if I would do so in the future, I'd only like to display the "Date" part.

Comment: A possibility would be to create a new level, between section and subsection, with format andd spacing such that it would emulate a sort of subtitle. Another would be trying to patch \section with the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: @MMA: Thanks, the solution in your link was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution, using `etoolbox`and `stackengine`. I define a `\subtitlesec` command, with the subtitle as an argument. This command has to be placed *before* the main title. I didn't check what happens with headers or title of contents, but you always can use the optional argument of section.

```
    \documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{stackengine}

    \newbool{secsub}
    \newcommand{\secsubtitle}[1]{\global\booltrue{secsub}\smash{\brlap{\mdseries\itshape #1}}}

    \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}{\ifbool{secsub}{\bigskip}{}}\global\setbool{secsub}{false}]%{}
    %
    \titlespacing*{\section}{0ex}{1.8\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}%

    \begin{document}

    \section{\secsubtitle{A subtitle}First section}

    A section title with a subtitle.

    \section{Another section}

    A section title with no subtitle.

    \end{document}
```

[image]