# How to align the section title and its subtitle?

Tags: titlesec

I'm using the `extarticle` class and I want to have a `\subtitle` command to add subtitles for sections. Here's what I expected:
[image: Expected effect]

Here is my current solution, quite ugly to be frank:

```latex
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\fsizept}
\setlength{\fsizept}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother

\newlength{\titleruleheight}
\setlength{\titleruleheight}{0.075\fsizept}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sffamily}
    {\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[\titleruleheight]}]
\newlength{\subtitleposfix}
\setlength{\subtitleposfix}{-2\baselineskip} %This should be linked with font size.
\newcommand\subtitle[1]{
    \vspace{\subtitleposfix}%
    \begin{flushright}%
        \emph{\emph{------}#1}%
    \end{flushright}\par}
\begin{document}
    \section{The title}
    \subtitle{The subtitle}
\end{document}
```

I find it hard to correctly align the title and subtitle. The `2\baselineskip` above is just an inaccurate approximation. The real value should depend on font size and configurations of the `titlerule` (as you can see, this `titlerule` depends on the font size given by `\fsizept`).

*I should add that I did some searches for existing questions such as
[this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69550/how-can-i-add-a-subtitle-to-a-section-title). But I didn't find a satisfied solution for my case.*

Anyway, is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my way for subtitle based to my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380116/120578):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\fsizept}
\newlength{\oldfsizept}
\newlength{\oldbaselineskip}
\newlength{\titleruleheight}
\newcommand{\readfsize}{%
\setlength{\fsizept}{\f@size pt}%
\setlength{\titleruleheight}{0.075\fsizept}%
}
\newcommand{\storeoldfsize}{%
\setlength{\oldfsizept}{\f@size pt}%
\setlength{\oldbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\titleruleheight}{0.075\oldfsizept}%
}
\makeatother






\newlength{\oldparskip}

\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\def\section{%
\@ifstar{\StarredSection}{\NonStarredSection}%
}
\def\StarredSection{%
\@ifnextchar[
{\StarredSectionWith}%
{\StarredSectionWithout}%
}
\def\NonStarredSection{%
\@ifnextchar[
{\NonStarredSectionWith}%
{\NonStarredSectionWithout}%
}
\def\StarredSectionWith[#1]#2{%
\@ifnextchar[
{\StarredSectionWithWith[#1]#2}%
{\StarredSectionWithWithout[#1]{#2}}%
}
\def\StarredSectionWithout#1{%
\@ifnextchar[
{\StarredSectionWithoutWith#1}%
{\StarredSectionWithoutWithout{#1}}%
}
\def\NonStarredSectionWith[#1]#2{%
\@ifnextchar[
{\NonStarredSectionWithWith[#1]#2}%
{\NonStarredSectionWithWithout[#1]{#2}}%
}
\def\NonStarredSectionWithout#1{%
\@ifnextchar[
{\NonStarredSectionWithoutWith#1}%
{\NonStarredSectionWithoutWithout{#1}}%
}
\def\StarredSectionWithWith[#1]#2[#3]{%
\def\mysubtitle{#3}%
\oldsection*{#2}
}
\def\StarredSectionWithoutWith#1[#2]{%
\def\mysubtitle{}%
\def\mysubtitle{#2}%
\oldsection*{#1}
}
\def\StarredSectionWithWithout[#1]#2{%
\def\mysubtitle{}%
\oldsection*{#2}
}
\def\StarredSectionWithoutWithout#1{%
\def\mysubtitle{}%
\oldsection*{#1}
}
\def\NonStarredSectionWithWith[#1]#2[#3]{%
\def\mysubtitle{#2}%
\oldsection[#1]{#2}
}
\def\NonStarredSectionWithoutWith#1[#2]{%
\def\mysubtitle{#2}%
\oldsection{#1}%
}
\def\NonStarredSectionWithWithout[#1]#2{%
\def\mysubtitle{}%
\oldsection[#1]{#2}
}
\def\NonStarredSectionWithoutWithout#1{%
\def\mysubtitle{}%
\oldsection{#1}
}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sffamily}
    {\thesection\readfsize}{1em}{}[{\storeoldfsize\vspace{-\dimexpr\oldbaselineskip}{\hfill\small\emph{\ifx\mysubtitle\empty\relax\else------\fi\mysubtitle}}\vspace{-\dimexpr0.7\oldbaselineskip}\linebreak\readfsize\rule{\linewidth}{\titleruleheight}}]

\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \section{The title}[My subtitle]
    Test text

\section{Title}{}
[This is just a text in square brackets]

\end{document}
```

This way the subtitle is an extra optional argument of section after the mandatory and you may add text in square brackets as done in my second section of the example.

[image]

Comment: Your solution is good, but sometimes there isn't a subtitle yet it still shows "--My subtitle". Is there a way to show nothing when there's no subtitle?

Comment: Also, the space between title texts and the rule is a little bit too large. I see you use a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` but this changes as the font size changes, so the final result would be unstable. Is there another way to just resembles my original `\titlerule`?

Comment: @XuJinwen .. Thanks ... didn't really tested ... just wanted to show the way ... Fixed now!

Comment: Your current solution works perfect so I have accepted it. I just wonder two things: 1) Why is there a `\storeoldfsize`? I didn't see the original value of `\baselineskip` and `fsizept` get changed. 2) What does the `\dimexpr` do? It seems fine removing them.

Comment: @XuJinwen ... 1) I store the values before the font size is been changed in `\small` to use these values and the new ones. They do change ... See for example what will happen if you add `\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont` instead of my `\small` command for the subtitle. 2) `\dimexpr` left there because I was making some additions etc of lengths... but realized that doesn't needed ... I would leave it there in case that an extra constant length would be used for the vertical spaces.