# How can I get subtitles for chapter titles to appear in the ToC, but not in the page headers?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

[From a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52963/how-can-i-get-extra-subtitles-for-chapter-titles-that-also-appear-in-the-toc), here's some code that enables subtitles for chapters, while also adding the subtitles to the ToC.

```
\newcommand\Chapter[2]{\chapter
[#1\hfil\hbox{}\protect\linebreak{\itshape#2}]%
{#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}%
}
```

Unfortunately this also adds the subtitles to the page headers. Is there a way of achieving the same effect in the chapter titles and ToC, but without having the subtitles in the page headers?

Comment: Do you really not want the subtitles in headers, or is it only because of the linebreak?

Comment: Do you want the subtitles in the headers?

Comment: Redefine the pagestyle with one of the pagestyle package (fancyhdr) (scrhead).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `\markboth`

```
\newcommand\Chapter[2]{\chapter
  [#1\hfil\hbox{}\protect\linebreak{\itshape#2}]%
  {#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}%
}
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand\Chapter[2]{\chapter
  [#1\hfil\hbox{}\protect\linebreak{\itshape#2}]%
  {#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Chapter{Title}{Subtitle}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

---

---

There is another possibility: try a  **KOMA-Script class** with the class option

```
headings=optiontoheadandtoc
```

Then the extended interpretation of the optional argument is activated and you can use

```
\newcommand\Chapter[2]{\chapter[
    tocentry={#1\hfil\hbox{}\protect\linebreak{\itshape#2}},
    head={#1}
  ]{#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}%
}
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand\Chapter[2]{\chapter[
    tocentry={#1\hfil\hbox{}\protect\linebreak{\itshape#2}},
    head={#1}
  ]{#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Chapter{Title}{Subtitle}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both these solutions worked. However the first solution also changed the formatting of the headers, apparently overriding some settings used for fancyhdr. So, even though I've not used Koma before, I'll go with the second suggestion.