# How to add a subtitle to some chapters?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

For some of the chapters of my thesis I want to add a subtitle under the chapter title(but not in the table of content).
I have tried `\chapter{Title \\  \large{subtitle}}`, which almost works, but the hyperref package doesn't like the `\\` command, and as a result my subtitle shows up very close under the title. Also this adds the subtitle into the table of content, which I don't want. Making the title italic makes it look a little better, but I still don't how to suppress it in the table of contents.

I have also tried `\chapter{title}{subtitle}` with 
`\newcommand\Chapter[2]{
  \chapter[#1: {\itshape#2}]{#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}}` 
as discussed in [How can I get extra subtitles for chapter titles that also appear in the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52963/how-can-i-get-extra-subtitles-for-chapter-titles-that-also-appear-in-the-toc) 
But that didn't seem to work for me, as the subtitle just appears as regular text in the body of the chapter in this case.

Comment: Note that the new macro you created is written with an uppercase `C`, so you have to call it with `\Chapter` rather than the usual `\chapter`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
\chapter[short title for toc]{long title}`
```

This is for long titles that should show up shortened in the toc.

```
\chapter[Title]{Title \\[1ex]\large{subtitle}}
```

should work fine. `\\[1ex]` creates an additional vertical space of `1ex`, i.e., the height of the letter `x`. Or create a macro for it:

```
\newcommand\Chapter[2]{\chapter[#1]{#1\\[1ex]\large#2}}
```

Usage: `\Chapter{title}{subtitle}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\Chapter}[2]{\chapter[#1]{#1\\[1ex]\large#2}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[Title]{Title\\[1ex]\large{subtitle}}
\Chapter{Title}{subtitle}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]
[image: result]
[image: result]

---

**edit:** For changing the default command `\chapter` with lower case `c`, one could do the following:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter % makes @ available for macro names
\let\oldchapter\chapter % save the old macro for chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{% redefine it
  \@ifstar{\oldchapter*}% if it's \chapter*, use the old command
  {\@ifnextchar[ \oldchapter \@Chapter}}% if it's \chapter[..] use old, else new command
\def\@Chapter#1{% the new command
  \@ifnextchar[ {\@sChapter{#1}} {\oldchapter{#1}}}% if there's a subtitle call \@sChapter, else the old \chapter
\def\@sChapter#1[#2]{\oldchapter[#1]{#1\\[1ex]\large#2}}% the subtitle macro
\makeatother % return to normal

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Title}
  \chapter{Title}[subtitle]

  % unchanged behaviour with traditional syntax:
  \chapter[title in toc]{Title}
\end{document}
```

I hope I have taken care of every case. That way, every default markup for latex should still work.

Comment: Great, thanks! One small drawback of this solution is that now I can't minimize/collapse the chapters for faster and easier navigation through the Source on Overleaf. But I can live with that.

Comment: @KatCS See my updated answer, you can use this if you want to stick to the old `\chapter`. Although there could be (?) some kind of mechanism to recognize a new chapter command as well?