# How can I add a subtitle to a chapter and add it to the table of contents?

Tags: formatting, chapters

I would like to add a subtitle to a chapter with the format `\scshape` and make it appear in the table of contents with the same format.

Something like this:[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at the answers of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52963/how-can-i-get-extra-subtitles-for-chapter-titles-that-also-appear-in-the-toc). Then, modify the formatting options to suit your needs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get extra subtitles for chapter titles that also appear in the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52963/how-can-i-get-extra-subtitles-for-chapter-titles-that-also-appear-in-the-toc)

Comment: I need it to be in a new line.

Comment: This is what the alternative definition of [the first answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52966/184389) does.

Comment: Just replace both `\itshape` by `\normalfont\scshape` to get small caps since by default the title is in bold and, by default, the combination of bold and small caps does not work.

Comment: Thank you so much!